# avoid output buffering error in serevr

Tags: php

I am developing w web site. Here I have included a thumnail page. It’s working well in my localhost. But when I uploaded its show me an error see

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /mydomain/demo1/admin/thumbnail.php:50) in /mydomain/demo1/admin/act-addVehicle.php on line 191
```

my code

```
if(move_uploaded_file ($tmpName,$path.$actual_image_name)){
                        $succ=1;
                        chmod("$add",0777);
                        $imgSucc=1; 
                            //strt image thumbnail
                        include("./thumbnail.php");
                        // ends
                        }else{ echo "Failed to upload file Contact Site admin to fix the problem"; 
                        exit;}
```

How I avoid this error
is there any settings in php ini ?

does anyone know ?
please reply

Comment: You have already sent content before trying to change the headers.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. You can do so by editing your own question, and adding it there, in the body of the question. It will help us help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php), everything you need to know here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028987/398242 For one thing, I don't see you using output buffering anywhere; you didn't really give enough info to help your case specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing *thumbnail.php*'s code its hard to tell exactly what's happening, but basically its outputting something before *act-addVehicle.php* on line 191 is setting another header.

Most likely a single space at the end of the script. Check after `?>` perhaps line 50 if just after.

You could wrap the include('thumbnail.php') into an ob_start() and ob_end_clean() but that will not solve the underlying issue of outputting before setting a new header.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of error typically comes from having a closing php tag in one of your file that is followed by some white space. This white space is sent to the browser when the script is executed BEFORE it executes a "header()" function.

For example, I would not be surprised that your thumbnail.php or act-addverhicule.php ends with a "?>" tag and that there is some white space after it.

As a good practice, it is always better to remove all closing php tag (the "?>") at the end of your files to avoid these kind of problems...

Answer (score 0):

of course. use [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) funciton somewhere in the beginning of your code